# 特定のクラス指定がある要素が、全体の半分出現した所に、コメント要素を挿入したい

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="article_content">
</div>
<div class="article_content">
</div>
<div class="article_content">
</div>
<div class="article_content">
</div>
```

上記のようなhtmlがあったとして、article_contentのクラスが付いているdivタグの数をカウントして、
その半分の数のところ（仮に11だとしたら、6）に`<!--コメントアウト-->`を挿入したいのですが、どのようにすれば実現できますでしょうか。

詳しい方、ご教示頂けますと、幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

上記の結果だと以下になります。

```
<div class="article_content">
</div>
<div class="article_content">
</div>
<!--コメントアウト-->
<div class="article_content">
</div>
<div class="article_content">
</div>
```

Comment: phpとjavascriptがタグに入っているのですが、どの言語に対しての話でしょうか？PHPで出力前に挿入するのか、出力後にJavaScriptで挿入するのかどちらでしょう？

Comment: JavaScriptの回答が既にあり、それでOKのようですので、PHPタグは削除しました。

Answer (score 1):

javascript で以下のような感じ

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("article_content");//ノードリスト
var len = divs.length;//要素数
if(len % 2)
    ++len;//奇数の時＋１
len /= 2;//0オリジン
var commentNode = document.createComment("コメントアウト");//コメントノードを作る
document.body.insertBefore(commentNode, divs[len]);//指定するエレメントの前に挿入。document.body は、この場合の親要素。
```